# How to solve Login pop when I click add to cart in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

[I want to remove this login page in woocommerce website please tell me how to fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSPCC.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable **Guest checkout** for this.
Follow this simple steps:

1. Open WooCommerce settings page from admin end.
2. Click *Accounts & Privacy* tab
3. In *Guest checkout* check the "Allow customers to place orders without an account".

I am also attaching a screenshot guide for better understanding.
[image]